# Email a full sized photo

Tags: android, email, bitmap, photo

I'm working on an app that, among other things, uses the device's camera to take a photo and then share it through email.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the app to take the full sized picture. It always sends a reduced in resolution version of the photo, although the camera is set to 5MP and quality when compressing is set to 100. Below you have my code:

```
    private void takePicture(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       if(requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
           picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           pictureView.setImageBitmap(picture);

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "Picture");
           values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "picture_ID");
           values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "");
           values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

           pictureUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
           OutputStream outstream;

           try{
               outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(pictureUri);
               picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
               outstream.close();
           }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
   }
```

.....

```
    share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, selectedType);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Notes + "\nLocation: " + selectedLocation+"\nOwner: " + selectedOwner
                    + "\nStatus: " + selectedStatus);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureUri);

            try{
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra for the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent with the key `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` which takes an URI to a file as the value. If you don't supply this extra, a size-reduced version of the taken image is returned to `onActivityResult()` with the data intent.

The reason for this is that a full-sized camera picture is simply too big for the intent system to handle *(it might work in theory, but slows down the whole intent processing a lot - intents should be as small as possible in general)*. So it can't be delivered like the small-size version.

To use this extra modify your `takePicture()` method, e.g. like this:

```
private void takePicture() {
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                               "image.jpg");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

This does work like your method above, with the exception that the camera app has written a full-size copy of the image into the file you specified when `onActivityResult()` is called.
This means you don't have to write the image to the disk on your own, just open it from there when your `onClickListener()` is executed like you did already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and explaining it so well. However, once I've added the new intent extra, once I take the picture nothing would happen. I press "Ok" in the Camera Menu and it would just stay there. Am I doing something wrong by replacing "..." with "image.jpeg"?

Comment: Yes, that has to be a valid path to a file. If you do it like this you end with "file.jpeg", which is not valid since you dont specify a directory. I updated the code a bit. Now it writes the image to the root of the [primary external storage directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) *(often thats the sd-card or a big internal flash memory)*.

Comment: In general this should work *(just tested in a sample project)*. Also I can't tell you why your app is crashing without the stacktrace. Since this is a different issue than the whole "small image" thing, I'd say please open a new question and include the stacktrace with the relevant piece of code.